# How do I exit Neverland (Big Ben/Clock Tower Area)?

Tags: kingdom-hearts, kingdom-hearts-1.5-remix

This is somewhat embarrassing, but I'm just playing through KH for the first time. How do I exit Neverland once you are done with the Clock Tower (or Big Ben area)? I'm not seeing a save point to get to the ship, or any way to exit this area.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out I just wasn't paying attention. It's on top of the clock tower near one of the windows ([see this video](http://youtu.be/AkkY3Jfuu5Y?t=28m28s)).